# Can't load large jpeg into a MTLTexture with MTKTextureLoader

Tags: metal, core-image, metalkit

I'm trying to load a large image into a MTLTexture and it works with 4000x6000 images. But when I try with 6000x8000 it can't.

func setTexture(device: MTLDevice, imageName: String) -> MTLTexture? {
        let textureLoader = MTKTextureLoader(device: device)

```
    var texture: MTLTexture? = nil

    //  In iOS 10 the origin was changed.
    let textureLoaderOptions: [MTKTextureLoader.Option: Any]
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let origin = MTKTextureLoader.Origin.bottomLeft.rawValue
        textureLoaderOptions = [MTKTextureLoader.Option.origin : origin]
    } else {
        textureLoaderOptions = [:]
    }

    if let textureURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: imageName, withExtension: nil, subdirectory: "Images") {
        do {
            texture = try textureLoader.newTexture(URL: textureURL, options: textureLoaderOptions)
        } catch {
            print("Texture not created.")
        }
    }
    return texture
}
```

Pretty basic code. I'm running it in an iPad Pro with A9 chip, GPU family 3. It should handle textures this large. Should I manually tile it somehow if it doesn't accept this size? In that case, what's the best approach: using MTLRegionMake to copy bytes, slicing in Core Image or a Core Graphics context...

I appreciate any help

Comment: What does the error that is thrown say?

Comment: "Image decoding failed."

Comment: I've seen this happen with palleted GIFs, and I think it also happens with some grayscale images. If it doesn't take up too much additional disk space, have you tried re-saving as a 24-bit JPEG or PNG with a different application? One other thing you could try is loading the image first with a `CGImageSource` and using the `newTexture(cgImage:...)` method instead, but this also has some rough edges. If all else fails, drawing into a bitmap context first is the most robust workaround I've found.

Comment: Some iOS devices have an upper limit of 4096x4096 for a texture, you will not be able to create an image larger than that. Newer devices have a larger max texture size.

Comment: @MoDJ The device in question (iPad Pro) has maximum 2D texture size of 8192x8192, and I think trying to create a texture that's too large would produce a different error, but that's a good note.

Comment: I already checked the documentation and Warren is right, it’s 8192x8192. I also tried the CGImage initializer route, but nothing. So far, the only thing that has worked is drawing to a CGContext and pass the data to the replace(region: bytes: ...) method of MTLTexture. It’s not very elegant, but works. I’ll upload the code tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your helpful comments I decided to load it manually drawing to a CGContext and copying to a MTLTexture. I'm adding the solution code below. The context shouldn't be created each time a texture is created, it's better to put it outside the function and keep reusing it.

```
    // Grab the CGImage, w = width, h = height...

    let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: w, height: h, bitsPerComponent: bpc, bytesPerRow: (bpp / 8) * w, space: colorSpace!, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)

    let flip = CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: -1, tx: 0, ty: CGFloat(h))
    context?.concatenate(flip)
    context?.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(w), height: CGFloat(h)))

    let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor()
    textureDescriptor.pixelFormat = .rgba8Unorm
    textureDescriptor.width = w
    textureDescriptor.height = h

    guard let data = context?.data else {print("No data in context."); return nil}

    let texture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor)
    texture?.replace(region: MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, w, h), mipmapLevel: 0, withBytes: data, bytesPerRow: 4 * w)

    return texture
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before, a texture would load on one device and not on another. I think it is a bug with the texture loader.

You can load in a texture manually using CGImage and a CGContext, draw the image into the context. Create a MTLTexture buffer, then copy the bytes from the CGContext into the texture using a MTLRegion.

It's not fool proof, you have to make sure to use the correct pixel format for the metal buffer or you'll get strange results, so either you code for one specific format of image you're importing, or do a lot of checking. Apples' [Basic Texturing example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/basic_texturing?language=objc) shows how you can change the color order before writing the bytes to the texture using MTLRegion.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it's a bug with the texture loader. I was able to load it this way. Created a CGContext with info from the CGImage. Flipped it with an CGAffineTransform and drew the CGImage. Created a MTLTexture with the same pixel format as the initial image and then replaced. In bytes I just passed the CGContext.data. However it takes a lot to load the image this way... Any idea how to improve it?